# node.js 'Hello World' on server

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

I'm new to node.js and I want to try and write a kind of 'Hello World' program, but I have a few questions.

I have the following code:

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.end("Hello World\n");
});

server.listen(8000);
```

I have a server from my university where I can run this code. But, `server.listen(8000)` automatically puts the IP to `128.0.0.1`. I don't really know if I have to change this and if I do, how to get the correct IP address (I would think I need the IP of the university server, but how do I get that?)

Another question I have is, once the server side is correctly configured, how can I send messages to this server?

Comment: Please only inquire on one topic per question.

Comment: From [the documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_requestlistener): "Begin accepting connections on the specified port and hostname. If the hostname is omitted, the server will accept connections directed to **any** IPv4 address (INADDR_ANY)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run

```
curl ident.me
```

to know your public ip.

Then bind your nodejs server like this

```
    var http = require('http');

    var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
      response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
      response.end("Hello World\n");
    });

    server.listen(8000, "your_ip");
```